# Use return data from one function in another and pass it to Smarty template

Tags: php, function, smarty

What I'm trying to do is to have one datatable probably as a template and passing different datas on different pages.

Example `functions.php`

```
function force() {
    global $DBconn;
    $q =  "SELECT * FROM table";
    $res = $DBconn->query($q);                              
    
    return $this->result;
}

function force_1() {
    global $DBconn;
    $q =  "SELECT * FROM table_1";
    $res = $DBconn->query($q);                              
    return $this->result;
}

function table() {

      echo '
         <table class="sortable">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Title
                </th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>';
                foreach ($this->result as $key) {
               echo ' <tr>
                    <td>
                        $key->name
                    </td>
                </tr>';
                }
            echo '</tbody>
        </table>';
    }
  return true;
}
```

Then in the page.php

```
$table = table();
$smarty->assign("table", $table);
```

and page.tpl

```
<div> {$table} </div>
```

Currently nothing showed on page, not even an error or something. So:

1. Is this the way that should be done? With using the returned result in either function and then pass it to the smarty template?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to use the smarty template (I never used it), but the `$table` variable holds what the function `table()` **returns** (in your case, the boolean value `true`). It should **return** a `string`, like this:

```
function force() {
    // corrected the function force return value, assuming that you are using PDO connection
    global $DBconn;
    $q =  "SELECT * FROM table";
    $res = $DBconn->query($q);                              
    return $res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

function table() {
  $arr = force(); 
  return 
  '
        <table class="sortable">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Title
                </th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>';
                foreach ($arr as $row) {
               echo " <tr>
                    <td>
                        $row['name']
                    </td>
                </tr>";
                }
            echo '</tbody>
        </table>';
}
```

You should be also careful with quotes when using variables inside a string.

EDIT:
If you are using mysqli class

```
function force() {
    global $DBconn;
    $q =  "SELECT * FROM table";
    return $DBconn->query($q);                              
}
function table() {
  $result = force(); 
  return 
  '
        <table class="sortable">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Title
                </th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>';
                //while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
               while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
               echo " <tr>
                    <td>
                        $row['name']
                    </td>
                </tr>";
                }
            echo '</tbody>
        </table>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This way is returning correct HTML but when I try to return with the foreach I've got `PHP Fatal error:  Using $this when not in object context in`

Comment: This is because $this variable is not defined.

Comment: In this case how should I "call" it from other functions?

Comment: Using global variables or with function parameters. But in your case it will not work because the $this variable is not returning anything in the force function

Comment: I just saw it.. it's a typo and should be `return $this->res;` but still.. I have tried also `return self::$res;` and the result is the same.

Comment: Call it from the table function. I edited the function to show you how to do it

Comment: And in the function still `return $this->res;`?

Comment: I corrected the function force()

Comment: Nothing is returned. What is strange is that even the `print_r($row['name']);` is not showed on the page. `print_r($arr)` showing `Resource id #13` which is something at least. But I just though about this approach and I don't see how this will help me since the desired outcome should be either `force()` or `force1()`... depending on which page is opened. The idea is to not have two identical tables but one and just populate based on the page

Comment: I don't know how you connect to the database. If you are using PDO or  mysqli class or anything else. I edited my answer

Comment: No, it doesn't even goes to the `while` loop for some reason. When I `print_r($result)` got resource #8. But if I printed inside the loop got nothing for either variable

Comment: try while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { instead of while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {; I edited again my answer